# $n = p^em$ and let $N$ be the number of subsets of order $p^e$ in a set of order $n$. is this congruence class of $N$ modulo $p$ $Z_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $n = p^em$ and let $N$ be the number of subsets of order $p^e$ in a set of order $n$. Would the congruence class of $N$ modulo $p$ just be $Z_n$?

Comment: What do you mean by $Z_n$? That is not usually used to denote a congruence class.

Comment: Z integer group. I'm a little confused on what the congruence class would be

Comment: Usually $\mathbb{Z}_n$ denotes the set of all congruence classes mod $n$, not some specified congruence class mod $p$.

Comment: would $ℤ_p$ be it  then

Answer (score 1):

It looks so hard, but I finally got it

just need the modular arithmetic

so in modulo $p$, we find the inverse of $(p^{e}-k)$ first

$(p^{e}-k)a≡1($mod$\ p)$

$-ka≡1($mod$\ p)$

$a≡-k^{-1}($mod$\ p)$

so $N=\binom{n}{p^{e}}$ may be $\prod_{k=0}^{p^{e}-1}(p^{e}m-k)(p^{e}-k)^{-1}$

but we should pay attention that the congruence class $\overline{0}$, always denoted by $0$, doesn't have a multiplication inverse

so $N=p^{e}m(p^{e})^{-1}\prod_{k=1}^{p^{e}-1}\overline{(p^{e}m-k)}·\overline{(p^{e}-k)^{-1}}=m\prod_{k=1}^{p^{e}-1}\overline{(-k)}·\overline{-k^{-1}}=\overline{m}$

that is, $N≡m($mod$\ p)$